# keeping a modal with iframe open for 30 seconds in shiny

Tags: r, shiny

In the first code below, the code opens an iframe in a modal with google.com.

I want to keep this modal open for 30 seconds and then close it if some condition is met in that amount of time, but for some reason the second code block doesn't work.

Working code:

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage()
server <- function(input, output, session) {
    showModal(modalDialog(
        title = "Test Modal",
        renderUI({
            tags$iframe(src="http://google.com", height=600, width=535)
        })
    ))
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Non-working code with 30 second timer:

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage()
server <- function(input, output, session) {
    showModal(modalDialog(
        title = "Test Modal",
        renderUI({
            tags$iframe(src="http://google.com", height=600, width=535)
        })
    ))
    continue <- TRUE
    start_time <- Sys.time()
    dt <- 0
    while(dt < 30){
        Sys.sleep(1)
        currentTime <- Sys.time()
        dt = as.numeric(currentTime - start_time)
    }
    someCondition = TRUE
    if(someCondition){
        removeModal()
    }
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `reactiveTimer` for this:

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage()
server <- function(input, output, session) {
    dt <- 0                       # Nb seconds

    # Timer one second
    autoInvalidate <- reactiveTimer(1000)
    
    observe({
        dt <<- dt + 1             # Increment one second

        someCondition = FALSE
        if(dt >= 30){             # After 30 seconds
            someCondition = TRUE
        }
        
        if(someCondition)
            removeModal()
        else
            autoInvalidate()      # Restart timer
    })
    
    showModal(modalDialog(
        title = "Test Modal",
        renderUI({
            tags$iframe(src="http://google.com", height=600, width=535)
        })
    ))
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```